# R add rows from colum in 1 table to the bottom of a column in a different table

Tags: r

I have a table (A) with a columns A1 and A2. They have numeric values. I want to take column A1 and A2 from table(B) and place them at the bottom of table(A) in columns A1 and A2. Basically, I have 2 datasets in different tables and I want to combine them into 1 so I can do analysis. Any help is appreciated!

Let's say I have Table A with 1 column and 3 rows: 1,2,3. I have Table B with 1 column and 3 rows: 4,5,6. I want the output to be 1 column with 6 rows: 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Use `rbind` i.e. `rbind(A, B)`

Comment: In addition, make sure A and B are both data frames and that their column names are the same, or it'll throw an error.

Comment: I tried that it doesn't give me the result I want. Let's say I have Table A with 1 column and 3 rows: 1,2,3. I have Table B with 1 column and 3 rows: 4,5,6. I want the output to be 1 column with 6 rows: 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: @AkhilNair `rbind` would also work with `matrix`

Comment: @TD Please update the data in your post

Comment: Hello - to help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Comment: I think it should work given that you have the same column names

Comment: It's giving me output of 2 rows with 3 columns.

Comment: Here is a reproducible example. `A <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:12,ncol=2));B <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:6, ncol=2));rbind(A,B)`

Comment: @akrun that does work. Is it because you did a matrix?

Comment: It is a dataframe (if you check the `str(A)`).  You can also create a data.frame directly `A <- data.frame(Col1=1:3, Col2=4:6)`,

Answer (score 2):

This is literally what rbind() does - two matrices or data.frames with the same columns can be bound together with the second object passed being bound as new rows to the first.  This won't work with vectors unless you turn them into matrices.

```
a = data.frame(A1=c(1,2,3),A2=c("A","B","C"))
b = data.frame(A1=c(4,5,6),A2=c("D","E","F"))
ab = rbind(a,b)
ab

#  A1 A2
#1  1  A
#2  2  B
#3  3  C
#4  4  D
#5  5  E
#6  6  F

a = data.frame(A1=c(1,2,3))
b = data.frame(A1=c(4,5,6))
ab = rbind(a,b)
ab

#  A1
#1  1
#2  2
#3  3
#4  4
#5  5
#6  6

a = matrix(c(1,2,3),ncol=1)
b = matrix(c(4,5,6),ncol=1)
ab = rbind(a,b)
ab

#     [,1]
#[1,]    1
#[2,]    2
#[3,]    3
#[4,]    4
#[5,]    5
#[6,]    6
```

Answer (score -1):

You might also look at `dplyr::bind_rows()`. It's the same as rbind but a lot faster, and handles a few common error cases well.